# How do I show or hide a div based on dropdown value populated by PHP query

Tags: php, jquery

Can someone help me with this...

I've managed to find code and get it to work using JQuery -collapse function when the user changes value away from "Rejected"

...what I can't get to work is if the dropdown selected value is populated from a query within PHP page and is set to anything other than "Rejected", I need it to hide the DIV else if it's pre-populated value is "Rejected" then show DIV and then if user changes the value on screen to say "No" then hide it. and again if they happen to select "Rejected" again then show it ETC.

```
<!-- Page Code -->
<div class="NotAcceptedReason">                                          
    <label class="font-bold text-danger">Please Enter Reason:</label>
    <textarea name="_initReviewCriteria002_Comment" class="form-control">
      My Reason Comment Here
    </textarea>
</div>
<!-- Selected Value pre-populated by db -->
<select class="form-control" name="_ReviewCriteria" id="ReviewCriteria">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="NA">NA</option>
    <option value="Rejected" selected>Rejected</option>
</select>

<!-- Script Function to handle onChange Event on dropdown selection -->
<script>
    $('.AcceptedReason').addClass('collapse');

    $('#ReviewCriteria').change(function () {
        opt = $(this).val();
        if (opt == "Yes") {                     
            $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('hide');
        } else if (opt == "No") {
            $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('hide');
        } else if (opt == "NA") {
            $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('hide');
        } else {
            $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('show');
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

ALSO...Some posts say that the use of 'hide'/'show' is depreciated in JQuery ver x? but I'm finding examples of the latest JQuery versions using this, which I find confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to trigger the `change()` for the first time, add the following line :

```
$(function(){
    $('.AcceptedReason').addClass('collapse');
    $('#ReviewCriteria').change();
    ....
})
```

Also your code could be more organized if you merge the conditions :

```
if (opt === "Yes" || opt === "No" || opt === "NA") {                     
    $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('hide');
} else {
    $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('show');
}
```

It will be better if you could use `slideUp/slideDown` functions, check example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  collapseDiv($('#ReviewCriteria').val());

  $('body').on('change', '#ReviewCriteria', function () {
    collapseDiv($(this).val());
  })
})

function collapseDiv(opt){
  if (opt === "Yes" || opt === "No" || opt === "NA") {                     
    $('.NotAcceptedReason').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('.NotAcceptedReason').slideDown();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page Code -->
<div class="NotAcceptedReason">                                          
  <label class="font-bold text-danger">Please Enter Reason:</label>
  <textarea name="_initReviewCriteria002_Comment" class="form-control">
    My Reason Comment Here
  </textarea>
</div>
<!-- Selected Value pre-populated by db -->
<select class="form-control" name="_ReviewCriteria" id="ReviewCriteria">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No" selected>No</option>
  <option value="NA">NA</option>
  <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't check the initial value of select box. Add the following code after onChange event :-

```
$(function(){
    var init_opt = $('#ReviewCriteria').val();
    if (init_opt == "Yes") {                     
        $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('hide');
    } else if (init_opt == "No") {
        $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('hide');
    } else if (init_opt == "NA") {
        $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('hide');
    } else {
        $('.NotAcceptedReason').collapse('show');
    }
});
```